# getting error about too many arguments discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so I made a code that's meant to send a message to someone when they react but once
I use the command !war, it gives me this error,(my code is below the error)

**

```
Ignoring exception in command war:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alastair/Desktop/Personal Coding/War bot/main.py", line 50, in war
    r = await ctx.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 442, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 370, in dispatch
    result = condition(*args)
TypeError: check() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: check() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**

```
@client.command()
async def war(ctx): 
    embed = discord.Embed(title='War', description='You are starting a war, do you want to continue?', color=0x00000)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojigood)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojibad)
    def check(r):
        return (r.emoji == emojigood or r.emoji == emojibad) and r.message == msg
    #Checks whether the message is the same, and the emoji is one of the accepted ones, and returns either True or False
    r = await ctx.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    #this is equivalent to a event listener within your command, it will stop there until a reaction that meets the requirements has been found 
    #(This won't block other commands and functions)
    if r.emoji == emojigood:
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title='War', description='Please now choose a country', color=0x00000)
        await channel.send(embed1=embed1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def war(ctx): 
    embed = discord.Embed(title='War', description='You are starting a war, do you want to continue?', color=0x00000)
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojigood)
    await msg.add_reaction(emojibad)
    def check(r, user):
        return (r.emoji == emojigood or r.emoji == emojibad) and r.message == msg
    #Checks whether the message is the same, and the emoji is one of the accepted ones, and returns either True or False
    r, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    #this is equivalent to a event listener within your command, it will stop there until a reaction that meets the requirements has been found 
    #(This won't block other commands and functions)
    if r.emoji == emojigood:
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title='War', description='Please now choose a country', color=0x00000)
        await channel.send(embed1=embed1)
```

`reaction_add` returns both Reaction and User. So you must use  `r, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)` Consider adding a timeout with

`r, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=20, check=check)`

`channel` is also undefined, think you meant to put `ctx` instead.

Comment: I get a problem 'bot is not defined'